# MySQL ERROR CODE 1265: what's wrong with my csv data?

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

A TABLE `shiyanyong` was created. 
After that, I got `Error Code: 1265.Data trancated forcolumn'income' at row 1` when i'm trying to load `csv file data` into `shiyanyong`.

**Is there something wrong with the csv data? or some other issues with the SQL CODE?**

At the same time, it works with

```
INSERT INTO shiyanyong VALUES('AA', 0.22);
```

1) TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE shiyanyong(
company_name VARCHAR(40),
income DOUBLE
);
```

2) LOAD DATA:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:\2018.csv'
INTO TABLE shiyanyong
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

3) The DATA of `2018.csv` for exaple like this:

```
company_name    income
A                  0.60
B                  1.80
C                  8.00
```

Comment: The data in your CSV isn't formatted matching your LOAD DATA command. In your csv, is there a tab between each field, or just a bunch of spaces? If it's a tab, replace the comma in your command with \t.

Comment: Thx. A bunch of spaces.

Comment: GOOD NEWS: It works out when i changed from `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ` to `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`. BAD NEWS: nothing is wrong with `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ` in my last `csv` file and i can not figure it out (the utf8-csv files are converted from EXCEL).

Comment: May I suggest avoid DOUBLE for income? Floating points are perfectly fine for multiplication (e. g. taxes, interest), but aren't for addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when i replaced `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` by `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`.